# Export to Excel directly from datasource with sorting and grouping for Kendo UI

Tags: c#, excel, sorting, kendo-ui, formatting

I am trying to export data to excel file directly from datasource, I am able to export it to excel but the problem is the data are not sorted the way I want it to be nor group in the way I want it to be.

No matter what I do, the output is not sorted the way I want it to be, it is just as same as the way the data is retrieved from datasource.

Sample Input data:
 
|Celine|29|Female|
|Kian|25|Male|
|Juan|40|Male|
|Satia|25|Female|
|Kulim|50|Male|
|Liz|15|Female|

Sample Output in excel:
|Liz|15|Female|
|Satia|25|Female|
|Celine|29|Female|
|Kian|25|Male|
|Juan|40|Male|
|Kulim|50|Male|

Here is a snippet of code I used:

```
$(".export-excel").click(function () {

    var from = new Date($("input#startDate").val()), to = new Date($("input#endDate").val());

    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: webApiUrl +
            "/data/getdata(startDateString='" +
                (from.getFullYear() + "-" + (from.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + from.getDate()) +
                "', endDateString='" + (to.getFullYear() + "-" + (to.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + to.getDate()) + "')",
                dataType: "json"
            },

            parameterMap: function (options, data) {
                var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                var d = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data);

                delete paramMap.$inlinecount;
                delete paramMap.$format;

                paramMap.$count = true;

                return paramMap;
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                return data.value;
            },
            total: function (data) {
                return data['odata.count'];
            },
            errors: function (data) {
            },
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    Age: { type: "string" },
                    Gender: {type:"string"}
                }
            },
            group: {
                field: "Gender"
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "Gender",
            dir: "asc"
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        groupable: true,
        filterable: true,
    });

    ds.fetch(function () {
        var data = this.data();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            rows.push({
                cells: [
                  { value: data[i].Name },
                  { value: data[i].Age},
                  { value: data[i].Gender}
                ]
            })
        }

        var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
            sheets: [
              {
                  columns: [
                    // Column settings (width)
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true }
                  ],
                  title: "Peaple_Report"
              }
            ]
        });
        //save the file as Excel file with extension xlsx
        kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: "Test.xlsx" });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.data() method holds the pristine data when not sorted or filtered ...

when you have applied any filter or sorting or grouping or paging ... you should read the data from .view() method ... that will give you the sorted/filtered data you are looking for ...

here is the documentation of .view() method - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-view